# create multiple brick in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, breakout

This is my code so far for creating bricks, and it works:

```
bricks = new Brick[5];     
this.createBricks(); 

private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         Brick brick = new Brick(0,0, Color.RED);  
         bricks[i] = brick;
    }
}
```

With this code I´m able to get one brick, but I´m quite sure that all my bricks now is on the same position. So I need help with how I write the positions(in my current code: 0,0) so that the bricks is displayed next to each other, in rows and columns.

Update:

```
Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[5][5];     
this.createBricks(); 

private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Brick brick = new Brick(i,j, Color.RED);  
            bricks[i][j] = brick;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what do you want the position to be instead of 0, 0? Perhaps `i, 0`? (So you have {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}...)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `i` to brick constructor:

```
private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         Brick brick = new Brick(i,0, Color.RED);  
         bricks[i] = brick;
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
OOOOO
-----
-----
-----
-----
```

or:

```
private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         Brick brick = new Brick(0,i, Color.RED);  
         bricks[i] = brick;
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
O----
O----
O----
O----
O----
```

or:

```
private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         Brick brick = new Brick(i,i, Color.RED);  
         bricks[i] = brick;
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
O----
-O---
--O--
---O-
----O
```

Assuming that first two constructor arguments are x and y axis of Brick matrix.
It depends on what your `Brick` constructor looks like.

**EDIT1**:
Answering to your question from comment:

```
Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[5][5];     
this.createBricks(); 

private void createBricks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
             Brick brick = new Brick(i,j, Color.RED);  
             bricks[i][j] = brick;
        }
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

Comment: Thanks! It works in x - direction and y-direction separately, but how do I write if I want bricks in both directions in the same loop?

Comment: Use two for loops. One loop in another. Look at "EDIT1" in my answer.

Comment: When I try this I get an error in the last line bricks[i][j] = brick;
It says "Array required, but brick found"

Comment: I think you left your Brick array declared as an array. It should be matrix just like in my example.

Comment: I updated my question, I think I declared it as a matrix, still doesn't work tho

Comment: Could you paste all code you are using to run this Brick thing?